# How to execute sort and limit query together with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a method written with node as follows to query from the collection

```
  query: function (model, conditon, options) {
            console.log(conditon, options);
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                options = options || {};

                model.find(conditon, {}, options).exec(function (error, data) {
                    if (error)
                        reject(error);
                    resolve(data);
                })
            })
        }
```

i want to fetch the data for the following query,

```
db.getCollection('_event').find({}).sort({'metadata.popularity': 1}).limit(10)
```

How should i modify the above method to support this query?

This is how i call the query function from another file,

```
 dbService.query(eventModel, { 'eventId': idRetrieved }, {});
 }).then(data => dbService.disconnectDb(data))
    .then(data => callback(data))
     .catch((error) => {
          dbService.disconnectDb(error).then(error => {
          console.log(error);
          callback({}, error);
})
```

Comment: `exec` returns a promise if you don't provide a callback, so why are you creating your own promise? Anyway, where are the sort and limit parameters coming from?

Comment: @JohnnyHK limit and sort i executed on mongo db, i want to know how to change the above code to support that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call [`sort`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-skip) and [`limit`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-limit) on the `Query` object returned from the `find` call.

But you don't need to create your own `Promise` as `exec` already returns a promise if you don't provide a callback.

```
function (model, condition, options, sort, limit) {
    return model.find(condition, {}, options).sort(sort).limit(limit).exec();
}
```